# uninitialized constant Gibbon::Request (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm trying to do Basic Mailing List Setup with Gibbon and Mailchimp.

I´m constantly getting this error when I  start up my rails server `rails s`

I even downgraded to version `gem 'gibbon',  '~>1.2.0'`

but still my log is looking like this

```
 /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/config/initializers/gibbon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gibbon::Request (NameError)
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/brainstore/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
dadi@Dadis-iMac brainstore (AddingMailChimp) $
```

I've been following this link http://cheshireoctopus.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/mailchimp-plus-gibbon-plus-rails-create-a-basic-sign-up-form/

and this one http://aspiringwebdev.com/e-mail-in-rails-with-mailchimp-and-mandrill-a-comprehensive-guide/

and I have done various modifications according to stackoverflow posts but still nothing seems to work.

I don´t have a clue what is going on here but it would be very helpful if someone could advise me...

this is my config/initializers/gibbon.rb

```
 require 'gibbon'
  gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "myAPIkey")
  Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
  Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

emailapi_controller.rb

```
 class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def subscribe

   @list_id = "myLISTid"
   gb = Gibbon::API.new

   gb.lists.subscribe({
   :id => @list_id,
   :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
   })

  end
end
```

Gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
 # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
 gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'

 # Use Capistrano for deployment
 # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

 group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
 gem 'pry-rails'
 end

 group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'

 gem 'dotenv-rails'

 end

 gem 'social-share-button'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass'
 gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
 gem 'carrierwave'
 gem 'mini_magick'
 gem 'puma'
 gem 'devise'
 gem 'country_select'
 gem 'braintree'
 gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production


 gem 'gibbon',  '~>1.2.0'


 group :test do
   gem 'minitest-rails'
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested I managed to fix this by doing the following.

in the Gemfile I changed `gem 'Gibbon'` to `gem 'gibbon', :git => 'https://github.com/amro/gibbon.git'`

then I changed the emailapi_controller.rb to

```
class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
 def subscribe
   @list_id = ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"]
 gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new

gibbon.lists(@list_id).members.create(
  body: {
    email_address: params[:email][:address],
    status: "subscribed"
  }
)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json{render :json => {:message => "You have been Successfully added to the list! :)"}}
    end
  end
end
```

the initializers/gibbon.rb is supposed to be like this:

```
 Gibbon::Request.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]
 Gibbon::Request.timeout = 15
 Gibbon::Request.throws_exceptions = false
```

and the MAILCHIMP_API_KEY and MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID are stored in a `application.yml`created by the figaro gem

hope this can help if someone stumbles on the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The current README for Gibbon refers to Gibbon 2.x. I suggest using a release version instead of pointing your Gemfile to github. e.g.

`gem 'gibbon',  '~>2.2.4'`

Answer (score 0):

Try in your Gemfile, not sure why bundler is not doing it by default

```
gem 'gibbon', '>= 3.4.0', require: 'gibbon'
```